# WCF Timeout .NET Core on Pod Startup

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, openshift

We have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 REST API which runs in OpenShift.  We are seeing instances where when new pods are created they are unable to connect to a SOAP service which is causing timeouts.  If we restart the pods most of the time the app is able to connect.

We are seeing this behavior after deployments and when auto scaling.  Again, it only occurs when the pod starts up and is intermittent.  We see other pods able to make those same SOAP calls at the same time from the same OpenShift nodes.

We have checked and all the OpenShift nodes have the firewalls opened and can connect to the SOAP service.

Anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If the WCF interface code operation time is relatively time-consuming, then when the number of connections is full, a new request will return a timeout error.

Please refer to the following code and add it to the wcf host host configuration file:

```
maxConcurrentCalls - Gets or sets a value that specifies the maximum number of messages actively processing across a ServiceHost.
maxConcurrentInstances - Gets or sets a value that specifies the maximum number of InstanceContext objects in the service that can execute at one time.
maxConcurrentSessions - Gets or sets a value that specifies the maximum number of sessions a ServiceHost object can accept at one time.
```

**The channel needs to be closed after the client call ends:**

```
client.Close();
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  .NET Core does not support hosting WCF services - we are calling a legacy SOAP service that is controlled by a vendor. I will double check that the clients are being closed.